# Recursive function as a static method

Tags: python, recursion, static

What is the right way of implementing a recursive function as a static method?

Here is how I have got it working atm. I was wondering if there is a "better" way of achieving this that leaves a cleaner memory footprint, looks more pythonic, etc.

```
class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def recursFun(input):
        # termination condition
        sth = MyClass().recursFun(subinput)
        # do sth
        return sth
```

Comment: Honestly, if you were looking for Pythonic, I would just not use `staticmethod`

Comment: how else would you do it in oop python?

Comment: I simply wouldn't make it part of the class, and make it a module-level function. Hard to say without more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't require an instance of the class to perform the correct name lookup; the class itself will do.

```
class MyClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def recursive_function(input):
        # ...
        sth = MyClass.recursive_function(subinput)
        # ...
        return sth
```

The qualified name is necessary because when you perform the name lookup, `recursive_function` won't be in scope; only `MyClass.recursive_function` will.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a `classmethod` instead:

```
class MyClass(object):

    @classmethod
    def recursFun(self, input):
        # termination condition
        sth = self.recursFun(subinput)
        # do sth
        return sth
    # end recursFun

#end MyClass
```

This also makes it easier to subclass the class, if you need to.